# Point in random-shape polygon?

Tags: python, algorithm

One can easily determine if a point is in a **convex** polygon with the famous Ray Casting Algorithm.

```
def point_inside_polygon(x, y, poly):
    """ Deciding if a point is inside (True, False otherwise) a polygon,
    where poly is a list of pairs (x,y) containing the polygon's vertices.
    The algorithm is called the 'Ray Casting Method' """
    n = len(poly)
    inside = False
    p1x, p1y = poly[0]
    for i in range(n):
        p2x, p2y = poly[i % n]
        if y > min(p1y, p2y):
            if y <= max(p1y, p2y):
                if x <= max(p1x, p2x):
                    if p1y != p2y:
                        xinters = (y-p1y) * (p2x-p1x) / (p2y-p1y) + p1x
                    if p1x == p2x or x <= xinters:
                        inside = not inside
        p1x, p1y = p2x, p2y
    return inside
```

But what if the polygon is not completely convex?

How may I determine whether a point is in a **random-shape** polygon given the boundary points?

Say I have a polygon of boundary points like so

[image]

How may I do it?

Best if in Python, but any generic solutions are also welcomed.

Comment: Doesn't the ray casting algorithm work in non-convex cases too? Wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: That is a very beautiful polygon sample you just drew, just like Picasso.
Here is a help on the algorithm : http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

Comment: Boundary *points*? Not edges? Are we supposed to interpolate the polygon from a noisy image? The picture you've given isn't a polygon by any stretch of the imagination. It's not even closed or contiguous.

Comment: @user2357112  Sorry for the confusion, you may close the open parts so as to take it as a polygon. It does not matter that much in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the ray casting method will work if you use a
**nonzero winding number rule** instead of the common **even-odd rule**.

This is the way it's explained in the Adobe's *Postscript Language Reference* (where the word "path" means the list of polygon vertices defining the polygon).

> The nonzero winding number rule determines whether a given point is
>   inside a path by conceptually drawing a ray from that point to
>   infinity in any direction and then examining the places where a
>   segment of the path crosses the ray. Starting with a count of 0, the
>   rule adds 1 each time a path segment crosses the ray from left to
>   right and subtracts 1 each time a segment crosses from right to left.
>   After counting all the crossings, if the result is 0 then the point is
>   outside the path; otherwise it is inside.

Answer (score 0):

Cast a ray, and count how many times the ray crosses the polygon. (This can get annoying and bug-prone if an edge lies exactly along the ray.) If it's an odd number, the point is in the polygon. Otherwise, it isn't.

Comment: So the ray casting method given in my question still works for this kind of complex polygon?

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: Looks like it, since it seems to be negating `inside` every time it finds a crossing. I haven't tested it, so I can't say for sure.